# boost bind template error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

```
//error C2784: 'HRESULT get_wrapper(T *,boost::function<R(void)>)' : 
//could not deduce template argument for 'boost::function<R(void)>' 
//from 'boost::_bi::bind_t<R,F,L>'

STDMETHODIMP CAttributeValue::get_Name(BSTR* pVal)
{
    return get_wrapper(pVal, boost::bind<BSTR>(&CAttributeValue::getNameCOM, this)); //error here
}

template <class T> HRESULT get_wrapper(T* pVal, boost::function<T()> GetVal)
{
    if(!pVal)
        return E_POINTER;
    HRESULT status = E_FAIL;
    try {
        *pVal = GetVal();
        status = S_OK;
    } catch (...) {}
    return status;
}

BSTR CAttributeValue::getNameCOM() const
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(TCHAR)==sizeof(wchar_t));
    return TStr2CComBSTR(_name).Detach();
}
```

Comment: [i-hate-c++]: C++ isn't that bad, at least it's not java.

Comment: I see you edited in my suggestion, but I was wrong, sorry.

Comment: thx anyway, it doesn't hurt so i'll leave it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it help to do this?

```
return get_wrapper<BSTR>(pVal, boost::bind(&CAttributeValue::getNameCOM, this));
//                ^^^^^^
```

There is a conversion from the type returned by `boost::bind` to `boost::function<T()>`, but since this parameter depends on a template argument, the compiler won't do any such conversions on your behalf.